# I'm getting negative output from a do-while loop, when it's supposed to stop at 0

Tags: c, cs50

I'm building a program for the problem set 1 of CS50x called "cash" that is written in C. I don't know how to make the function cant_de_monedas work on my main function, and when I tried to print the return "dinero" after each loop it keeps counting down even after it reachs 0.

```
//inclusión de librerías
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


//llamado de la función cant_de_monedas para su funcionamiento en main
float cant_de_monedas(float dinero, int monedas);

int main(void)
{
//input del dinero principal
    float dinero = get_float("Insertar dinero: ");
//ajuste de monedas a 0
    int monedas= 0;
//llama a la función cant_de_monedas
    float cambio = cant_de_monedas(dinero, monedas);
    
    printf("Cantidad de monedas de vuelto: %i\n", monedas);
}


//analiza las monedas necesarias de cambio para una cantidad de dinero variable en centavos de dolar
float cant_de_monedas(float dinero, int monedas)
{
//suma una moneda mientras el dinero sea mayor o igual a 25
    do
    {
        monedas++;
        dinero=dinero-25;
        printf("%f\n", dinero);
    }
    while (dinero>=25);
//suma una moneda mientras el dinero se encuentre entre 25 y 10 incluído
    do
    {
        monedas++;
        dinero=dinero-10;
        printf("%f\n", dinero);
    }
    while (dinero<25 && dinero>=10);
//suma una moneda mientras el dinero se encuentre entre 10 y 5 incluído
    do
    {
        monedas++;
        dinero=dinero-5;
        printf("%f\n", dinero);
    }
    while (dinero<10 && dinero>=5);
//suma una moneda mientras el dinero se encuentre entre 5 y 1
    do
    {
        monedas++;
        dinero=dinero-1;
        printf("%f\n", dinero);
    }
    while (dinero<5 && dinero>1);
//suma una moneda mientras el dinero sea 1
    do
    {
        monedas++;
        dinero=dinero-1;
        printf("%f\n", dinero);
    }
    while (dinero==1);
    return monedas;
}
```

The output that I get from it is:

```
$ ./cash
Insertar dinero: 51

26.000000
1.000000
-9.000000
-14.000000
-15.000000
-16.000000

Cantidad de monedas de vuelto: 0
```

Comment: The body of a `do-while` loop is always executed at least once. You don't want that. What you want is a simple `while` loop.

Comment: when working with `float` values, any literals used to modify the value should also be `float`,  I.E.1.0f or `10.0f`, etc.  Also, `float` cannot exactly represent all values.  Suggest, after obtaining the value, to multiply by 100, and cast to `int`

Comment: regarding: `while (dinero==1);` This is unlikely to ever be true because the value in `dinero` is unlikely to be exactly 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have three remarks:

1. You seem to be working with floating point numbers, while there can be quite some rounding issues with those. I'd advise you to work with integer values only.
2. If you do need to work with floating numbers, I advise you to use `double` instead of `float`.
3. Instead of a `do-while`, just use a `while` (imagine the condition is never met, then the loop is not executed at all).

Comment: In this specific case, in which the application is dealing with money, IMHO `float` is enough. Since the littlest unit is usually `0.01$` (or €£¥₩) any precision issue would be managed just at print phase with `printf("%0.2f\n", dinero);`.